# Why do some pools require a worker name with an underscore and others require a period?

Tags: mining-pools

The majority of pools I see that they use a period such that:

`username.workername`

others use:

`username_workename`

I see that it definitely is not interchangeable.  How come some pools use underscore (such as bitminter and btcguild)  and others use a period (like gigahash.io)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These are just arbitrary rules. Made by the pool admin. Really doesn't matter.